# Efficient way to create similarity matrix (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I've got one list with 1M vectors. What I want to do is calculate the similarity between each of them!

```
len(list_vec) = 1000000
```

Result:

```
          V1 V2 ... V1000000
V1        1   a ...   b
V2        a   1 ...   d
...             ...
V1000000  b   d ...   1
```

The similarity is given by

```
def cos_sim (v1, v2):
   return 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(v1, v2)
```

Tried with a for-each loop, but it is impossible to do. I think numpy can't handle such a huge matrix as well. Any ideas with pandas?

Comment: You should check out scipy, in particular https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html. I think that `pdist` will do what you need. I would also point you to the fact that your function already uses scipy.

Comment: If I run pdist(my_vector, my_metric), do I get a len(my_vector)**2 size vector?

Comment: You will get a square "n by n" matrix, where n is the number of your original vectors.

Comment: You might want to rethink your problem. Do you really need to create an all-vs-all similarity matrix? A simple back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests you'll need around 4TB of memory to store this matrix (using np.float64 for distances). What are you trying to achieve in the broader sense?

Comment: I've got 1M embeddings (for sentences). I'd like to cluster those sentences by calculating the similarity between them.

Comment: @pavel Actually, `pdist` returns a condensed distance matrix, so it isn't a square matrix. It is flat, and of size "n^2/2 - n"

Comment: @AndrewGuy, oh, is it? I must've gotten it confused with some other method.

Comment: The outcome has (499500,) shape, it isnt a squared matrix...

Comment: How can I turn it into a squared matrix? any suggestions?

Comment: Use `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` to convert to a square matrix (although not recommended because of the extra memory requirements).

Comment: @notyourdaddybro I would recommend looking at some of the clustering methods in `sklearn` that support large numbers of samples - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means  Most of the methods that support large numbers of samples won't require computation of the full distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compute the full distance matrix on your samples. It doesn't scale well, and with 1 million samples you'll need 4TB of memory.

If you're looking to find the nearest neighbours (i.e. for K-nearest neighbours), perhaps use a [KD-tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). If you're looking to do something like K-means, then processing in batches would help.

With that said, unless there is a requirement that you code an implementation from scratch, I would suggest going with one of the clustering techniques in `sklearn` (in the comments, OP stated that they are trying to cluster sentence embeddings). For data of this size, [mini-batch K-means](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans) may be appropriate. Or choose another [clustering method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods) with good scalability. Be aware that some of these clustering methods (i.e. K-means) will be sensitive to scaling of dimensions, so consider the need to do feature scaling before clustering.

*(I realise this doesn't explicitly answer the question as stated, but I think in this case a "don't do X, do Y instead" answer is justified)*